# Finding the eigenvalues of a discrete laplacian on an infinite lattice

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, graph-laplacian, tridiagonal-matrices, infinite-matrices

If we define the Laplacian as a square matrix with zeroes on the diagonal, and $-1$ on the diagonals exactly above and below the main diagonal, and $0$ everywhere else, how would one go about finding its eigenvalues?

$$\!\!\begin{pmatrix}
\ddots \\
& \;\;\;0 & -1 \\
& -1 & \;\;\;0 & -1 \\
& & -1 & \;\;\;0 & -1 \\
& & & -1 & \;\;\;0 & -1 \\
& & & & -1 & \;\;\;0 \\
& & & & & & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}$$

Something of this sort.

The reason I wish to find this is because I have a Hamiltonian on an discrete and infinite $L^2$ space, and it takes the form of this matrix. I’d like to diagonalize this and find the spectrum of it.

Comment: Well, you can add an infinite identity matrix to this one to make the main diagonal non zero. Do we know a solution to that? And yes, the matrix is infinite!

Comment: You can, but it still wouldn't be a Laplacian. You would need to add the identity twice.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1835861/339790). The eigenvalues will be samples of a cosine.